Picocli unit test failed for registering subcommands programmatically
In picocli we can register subcommands declaratively and programmatically.
It works both way, but the unit test according the docs failed for the programmatically version.
This is the unit test:
@Test
void testApp() {
    App app = new App();
    CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(app);
    int code = commandLine.execute("sub1", "param1");
    assertEquals(0, code);
}

variant 1 declaratively ✅
@CommandLine.Command(name = "foo", subcommands = { App.Sub.class })
public class App {

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(new App());
      System.exit(commandLine.execute(args));
  }

  @CommandLine.Command(name = "sub1", description = "sub1")
  public static class Sub implements Runnable {

    @CommandLine.Parameters
    public String [] params;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Sub " + params[0]);
    }
  }
}

variant 2 programmatically ❌
@CommandLine.Command(name = "foo")
public class App {

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(new App())
        .addSubcommand("sub1", new App.Sub());
      System.exit(commandLine.execute(args));
  }

  @CommandLine.Command(name = "sub1", description = "sub1")
  public static class Sub implements Runnable {

    @CommandLine.Parameters
    public String [] params;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Sub " + params[0]);
    }
  }
}

This is very confusing and I spend some hours for detecting that maybe not my application code is missing something.....
I assume, that I need the programmatically way, so how the unit test should look like for this variant ?
Kind regards
Dominik

Instead of calling the subcommand method, call the addSubcommand method to register subcommands programmatically.
See section Registering Subcommands Programmatically in the manual:
CommandLine commandLine = new CommandLine(new Git())
        .addSubcommand("status",   new GitStatus())
        .addSubcommand("commit",   new GitCommit())
        .addSubcommand("add",      new GitAdd())
        .addSubcommand("branch",   new GitBranch());
…

Secondly, note that in the programmatic variant, the subcommand is added/registered in the main method of the App class, but the test doesn’t call the main method, so the subcommand is not registered in the test.
One idea is to have a static createCommandLine method in App, which is called from App.main as well as from the test to ensure that the test is testing exactly what is used in the application.

Sorry, my failure ... I've used the API method addSubcommand already, it was only a typo in the example of the question above. So I've edited the example but the question still remains: the unit test failed for the programmtically variant. Any help ???

I updated my answer. The test is incorrect: it doesn’t add the subcommand.
